# Pygame window will not open

Tags: python, pygame

I'm completely new to Python and I just started learning Pygame. I'm trying to work with drawing shapes right now, but I can't get the window to open. Idk what the problem is, here's my code:

```
`#import libraries
import pygame
import math
 #init pygame
 pygame.init()

 #clock
 clock = pygame.time.Clock()

 #window screen

screen_height_x = 500
screen_height_y = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_height_x, screen_height_y))

#RGBA colors
 Black = (0, 0, 0)
 White = (255, 255, 255)
 Blue = (0, 0, 255)
 Red = (255, 0, 0)
 Green = (0, 255, 0)

 #program
 running = True
 while running:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
       running = False

screen.fill(Black)
pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(30)
 #Quit
pygame.quit()
quit()`
```

Comment: Pygame has some built in colors you can access, e.g. `pygame.Color("black")`. See the [source](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/main/src_py/colordict.py) for the full list of names, including five variants of _orange_.

Answer (score 2):

You're immediately quitting the main loop and you also aren't drawing anything. Try this instead:

```py
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill(Black)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)

#Quit
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Disclaimer: I cannot try this out at the moment but it should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using the if statement and now it just gives me a pygame error. "display Surface quit". Do you have an idea on what this means?

Comment: @HJ_Whitt1546 not sure, in which line do you get this? Also note that my code isn't complete, you still need all the previous things you had before.

Comment: Yeah. I implemented all the previous things you've mentioned and shown me. Its on line 31

Comment: @HJ_Whitt1546 that's strange because the code works perfectly on my system (pygame 2.1 on Ubuntu). That makes me think there's some other problem, perhaps specific to your platform.

Comment: You might be right, I'll try it on a Linux system sometime. But I found an alternative anyways during my software design class, but thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a class part of the projet or the main class ? If it is the main class, you it should contain a main function.

If this is the main function, you should declare it by adding `def main():` before the `pygame.init()` 
And add the module to exectute this as the main script under Quit

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Sorry, im french my english is not the best aha !

Comment: How does this address any of the original code's problems?